# How do I reduce the codes require to check error

Tags: batch-file

We check error using

```
if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (do something)
```

but this is littered everywhere in the batch file.

1) Is the a way to encapsulate it to log and exit program upon error?

2) how do I log the bat file line number that is causing the error?

Comment: How short do you want your error handling? Do you only log an error or do you need to do more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO y|FIND "y" >NUL
CALL aberr matching y and y
pause
ECHO x|FIND "y" >NUL
CALL aberr matching x and y
pause
ECHO y|FIND "z" >NUL
CALL aberr matching y and z
pause

GOTO :EOF
```

The above is a testing scenario, setting `errorlevel` to 0, 1, 1 in succession, then `CALL`ing then batch `aberr.bat` to analyse the result.

Here's `aberr.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO :EOF
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% found %*
EXIT
```

Note here that there is no `SETLOCAL` (which would set `ERRORLEVEL` to zero) and that the routine `EXIT`s.

Consequence is that if `aberr.bat` is on the `PATH` then the message produced would show the errorlevel found plus any text that was on the `CALL aberr` line after `CALL aberr`.

You could place a `PAUSE` after the `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` line to show the result, or log the result to a file by using

```
>>logfile.txt ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% found %*
```

Answer (score 1):

at 1) How to log and exit the batch [Exit from nested batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655690/463115)
at 2) [How to get the current line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609390/463115)

Mix them and you get it.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd. & REM *** Set the errorlevel to 0
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    call :getLineNumber errLine uniqueID4711    -2
    call :log ERROR: in line !errLine!
)

set /a n=0xGH 2> nul & REM Force the errorlevel to !=1
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    call :getLineNumber errLine uniqueID4711    -2
    call :log ERROR: in line !errLine!
)
echo all OK
exit /b

:log
>error.log echo %*
call :HALT
exit /b

:HALT
call :__halt 2> nul
exit /b

:__halt
()

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:GetLineNumber <resultVar> <uniqueID> [LineOffset]
:: Detects the line number of the caller, the uniqueID have to be unique in the batch file
:: The lineno is return in the variable <resultVar> add with the [LineOffset]
SETLOCAL
for /F " usebackq tokens=1 delims=:" %%L IN (`findstr /N "%~2" "%~f0"`) DO set /a lineNr=%~3 + %%L
( 
  ENDLOCAL
  set "%~1=%LineNr%"
  goto :eof
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
...
if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 Call :LogAndExit "some explanation"
...
GoTo :EOF

:LogAndExit
Echo %Date% %Time% - %~1>>Log.txt
Exit /B
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question. AFAIK, what you want is not possible. Unless you can concatenate all commands with `&&` (see http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx)