# Is there a way to write Ctrl-C in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

#### Is there a way to use `ctrl-c` in a batch-file without the need for the user to input `ctrl-c`?

---

In batch files and command prompt, the input `ctrl-c` will break a command like a `for` loop or a batch job in general. I was messing around to see if the actual `break` command had any use (it really doesn't, even when command extensions are on it is useless) and I thought "*is there a way to write ctrl-c in a batch file or on the command line?*" The first thing that I tried was making a step `for` loop using `for /l` with an `if` statement in the `do` section saying `if %a LEQ 9500 (^^C)` as `^C` is how it is shown when you input`ctrl-c` to break something. When I ran the full command (`for /l %a in (10000, -1, 1) do (if %a LEQ 9500 (^^C))`)  it did the error `'^C' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` when `%a` got below 9500. I also tried this same thing in a batch file with `%%a` and it had the same error. I then tried using `break` as well with extensions on and off and still it didn't work.

---

#### What I want to learn

So overall I want to figure out the command-equivalent of `ctrl-c` and how to use it.

Comment: Am I missing something in how you've worded your question, but is the end result not just `"Can a loop be broken when a certain condition is met?"` In which case all you need is a conditional test followed by `Goto :Label`, or,  If the loop exists in a subroutine `Exit /B`

Comment: I am aware of how to do that but I am more looking for something that allows me to write `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5859)

Here's the exit function by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) that uses `-1073741510` as exit code to emulate `ctrl-c` in a .bat script:

```
:ExitBatch - Cleanly exit batch processing, regardless how many CALLs
if not exist "%temp%\ExitBatchYes.txt" call :buildYes
call :CtrlC <"%temp%\ExitBatchYes.txt" 1>nul 2>&1
:CtrlC
cmd /c exit -1073741510

:buildYes - Establish a Yes file for the language used by the OS
pushd "%temp%"
set "yes="
copy nul ExitBatchYes.txt >nul
for /f "delims=(/ tokens=2" %%Y in (
  '"copy /-y nul ExitBatchYes.txt <nul"'
) do if not defined yes set "yes=%%Y"
echo %yes%>ExitBatchYes.txt
popd
exit /b
```

Add this at the end of your script and you can just use `call :ExitBatch`

if you want to see the prompting message you call the `:CtrlC` function

Comment: So this works as intended, but it is not emulating `ctrl-c`, it is just exiting the batch file with exit code `-1073741510`. When I call your function in a for loop it doesn't break the loop, it just exits the script. When I enter `ctrl-c` with no loops running, it also brings the option of `Terminate batch job? [Y/N]` but with your function it just exits the file without an option for user input similar to `choice`.

Comment: @NekoMusume then use only `:CtrlC` function - it should have option to ask you to exit.

Answer (score 0):

The [`STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444765/why-does-a-non-interactive-batch-script-think-ive-pressed-control-c) method is language-dependent, that's why **@dbenham** included the

```
copy/-Y nul [ANY FILE THAT EXISTS]
```

which outputs

> [Rubbish] (Yes/No/All)?

in this case, we obviously want `Yes` (or in whatever language the machine is running on), so `delims=(/` is needed.

---

Here is a language-independent solution, like `Ctrl-C`, it terminates all batch processing immediately:

```
@echo off

FOR /L %%I in () do call:break 1000

NEVER REACHED

:break RETURN_EXIT_CODE
cmd /c exit %1
call:halt >nul 2>&1


:halt - Infinite Recursion
call:halt
```