# How to close java desktop application from .bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a java stand alone application. I build a jar, and I create a .exe file from this jar file.

Then I can start the application by double click on it. Now I need to create a .bat file to close the exe program. Now I build a .bat file like this:

```
TASKKILL /F /PID easyManagement.exe
pause
```

the script is executed without error but the program easyManagement is every time on.

**EDIT**
In task manager I can display my program like this:
[image]

This code:

```
TASKKILL /IM easyManagement.exe
```

run without error but the application is on every time.

Answer (score 0):

The keys Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z will end the running of a batch file. Check out this link: [Is there a way to write Ctrl-C in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781729/is-there-a-way-to-write-ctrl-c-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: I don't understand what the ctrl c and ctrl z commands have to do with it?

Comment: You got it backwards - they try to kill a DESKTOP application FROM a batch script, not kill a batch script.

Comment: Yes I shoudl to kill desktop application from batch script

Comment: The link explains how to stop a batch file from running, from within a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong parameter for the taskkill command.
The /PID expects a pid and not the name of the program you want to stop.
Use `TASKKILL /IM easyManagement.exe`
or `TASKKILL /F /IM easyManagement.exe` to force the program to stop.
The /F might cause problems in the program you want to stop.

Comment: I think that there is a problem for my program write in java. I just edit my first question