# Batch: How to Jump from subrpgram to the exit of the main program?

Tags: batch-file, goto

I have a control_script.cmd that works as it is but is a little hard to read. Basically, I want to quit my script when the first program returns an error.

```
set text=converting something...
call %libdir%\1_convert_xlsx.cmd 
set rvalue=%errorlevel%
call :check_errorlevel !rvalue! "!text!"
if !rvalue! geq 1 goto :my_error_handler

set text=loading something...
call %libdir%\2_load_something.cmd 
set rvalue=%errorlevel%
call :check_errorlevel !rvalue! "!text!"
if !rvalue! geq 1 goto :my_error_handler

:check_errorlevel 
set rvalue=%~1
set text=%~2
echo do something with rvalue and text
exit /b 0

:my_error_handler
exit /b 1
```

it would be much nicer if I could move the if-clause into the check_errorlevel part, like

```
call %libdir%\1_convert_xlsx.cmd 
call :check_errorlevel %errorlevel% "converting something..."

call %libdir%\2_load_something.cmd  
call :check_errorlevel %errorlevel% "loading something..."

:check_errorlevel 
set rvalue=%~1
set text=%~2
echo do something with rvalue and text
if !rvalue! geq 1 goto :my_error_handler
exit /b 0


:my_error_handler
exit /b 1
```

But here I face the issue that :my_error_handler is not defined within :check_errorlevel and I do not see any other way to go directly from :check_errorlevel to the end of my cmd. Is there any?

Best regards, Peter

Comment: Is there any reason your not just using `If  not errorlevel 0 (command)` as opposed to a resource intensive call function? - Given that your already using delayed expansion, it could easily be scripted as a macro to capture the errorlevel, perform the test and output a string relevant to the command being tested via substring modification. The macro method avoids adding another environment stack to the command processor

Comment: The reason you cant just exit /b to the end of the script is that when you use call, the called label is executed as an independent child environment that returns control to the parent environment after execution.

Comment: @T3RR0R: child environment; yes but what's the bypass? 
reason: actually, check_errorlevel contains a tree of if-else statements. I am just cutting the code short.

Comment: The bypass is not to use a subroutine that must first return control to the script. You could do a hard `exit`, however I assume that is not desired here.

Comment: right, maybe I just try your macro style.

Comment: You'll need `exit /B` before `:check_errorlevel`. Anyway, why not just doing `call "%libdir%\….cmd" || echo Something went wrong.& exit /B`?

Comment: hehe, the reason is that I am not familiar with | :-) on the other side better learn pipe then learn macro I guess... thank you.

Comment: @aschipfl for a quick check I just found "|" which might work for me. Do you have any link to the usage of "||" for me? Is || something like "execute right statement only if left statement returns an error?! ... whats means that errorlevel is geq 1, right?

Comment: found it myself... || equals if errorlevel neq 0

Comment: Great! Anyway, take a look at [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). By the way, my previous suggestion should have been `call "%libdir%\….cmd" || (echo Something went wrong.& exit /B)`, because without parentheses, `exit /B` will always run…

Comment: For a real STOP in a nested call, try a look at [Exit from nested batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655345/exit-from-nested-batch-file) and the another one [Does Windows batch support exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31445330/463115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%So after @aschipfl hint, I am going to go for the code below. I actually still need to test it but I am having a good feeling here.

```
call %libdir%\1_convert_xlsx.cmd 
call :check_errorlevel %errorlevel% "converting something..." || goto :my_error_handler

call %libdir%\2_load_something.cmd  
call :check_errorlevel %errorlevel% "loading something..." || goto :my_error_handler

goto :all_fine

:check_errorlevel 
set rvalue=%~1
set text=%~2
echo do something with rvalue and text
if %rvalue% GEQ 1 ( set my_errorlevel = 1 ) else ( set my_errorlevel = 0 )
REM notice that this errorlevel only transfers the input-errorlevel and is not an errorlevel by itself.
exit /b %my_errorlevel%

:my_error_handler
exit /b 1

:all_fine
exit /b 0
```

edit:  {} to () thanks to stefano

Comment: `if %rvalue% GEQ 1 { set my_errorlevel = 1 } else { set my_errorlevel = 0 }` surely doesn't work. It should be `if %rvalue% GEQ 1 (set my_errorlevel=1) else (set my_errorlevel=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the macro style I mentioned

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // macro definition within delayed expansion environment requires exclaimation marks to be thrice escaped.
rem // outer For %%n loop uses If ()Else construct to capture the trailing string within the output variable at the time of expansion.
Set "CHKErr=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (If Not "^^^!Errorlevel^^^!"=="0" (Echo/Failed [^^^!Errorlevel^^^!] - ^^^!Output^^^!&Endlocal &Goto :EOF)Else (Echo/Success - ^^^!Output^^^!))Else Set Output="
 Call :truelabel 2> Nul
 %CHKErr%:truelabel
 Call :falselabel 2> Nul
 %CHKErr%:falselabel
 Echo/You'll never see this on fail.
Goto :Eof

:truelabel
Exit /B 0
```